# Can't send php mail()

Tags: centos, php, email, sendmail

I just migrated to a new server and apparently I can't send a mail.
I've "ipb board" installed there and every time I send a mail I get the following in error_log
`sh: -t: command not found`

```
ls -l /usr/sbin/sendmail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Dec 19 22:57 /usr/sbin/sendmail -> /etc/alternatives/mta

rpm -qa | grep send
sendmail-milter-8.14.4-8.el6.x86_64
sendmail-8.14.4-8.el6.x86_64
sendmail-cf-8.14.4-8.el6.noarch
```

Comment: And ls -l /etc/alternatives/mta ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I added `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i` to php.ini